# Change Edittext accessibility announcement for inputType password

Tags: android, android-edittext, accessibility, talkback, android-textinputedittext

By default if the inputtype of edittext is "numberPassword", the talkback announce the field as "Password + {hint}". Since I use the edit box for masking some input fields other than password, I want the talk back to announce the hint only. Is there any way to do it?

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/textInputRoutingNumber"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLength="9"
                        android:hint="Enter Routing Number"
                        android:inputType="numberPassword" />
```

Comment: `I want the talk back to announce "Masked + {hint}" or just "{hint}".` what is this mean by?

Comment: I mean, I don't want the talkback to announce " Password {Enter routing number} ". Instead I want it to announce "{Enter routing number}" only. Password sounds weird in routing number context.

Comment: are you setting `Password {Enter routing number}` anywhere in your code?

Comment: No, but since the hint is "Enter routing number" and input type is "numberPassword" talkback announce "Password Enter routing number edit text"

Comment: Can you post your talkback code here once?

Comment: I have not written any code for talkback. I am reporting whatever is supported by default for TextInputEditText.

Comment: Not sure whether this will work as intended, but you could try to set input type to just a number and apply https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod to EditText.

Comment: @sigute No, it didn't work.